# Non-static global variable vs. global static __thread variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, thread-local

If I define a static `__thread` variable in global scope, is it equivalent to the regular non-static global variable?  In other words, are the following two variables equivalent to each other if they are all in global scope:

```
int regular_global_int;
static __thread int static_thread_local_int;
```

If the answer is no, can I know what's the major different between these two and when should I use which one?

Comment: __thread isn't part of the C++11 standard, I believe it's unique to GCC. Do you mean thread_local?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I mean `__thread` in gcc.  Will change the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables, and more generally namespace-scope variables, automatically have static storage duration when not declared with a storage class specifier. At namespace scope, `static` does not mean "static storage duration"; it means the variable has internal linkage. Hence

```
int x;
static int x;
```

at namespace scope both declare `x` with static storage duration but the two declarations are nevertheless not the same as the first declaration gives `x` external linkage but the second gives it internal linkage.

In the case that you write

```
static thread_local int x;
```

the `thread_local` storage class specifier causes `x` to have thread-local storage duration (rather than static storage duration) whereas `static` itself again has its usual meaning at namespace scope. So `x` is thread-local *and* it has internal linkage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still not quite understand.  So what's the difference between a variable with static storage duration vs. one with thread local + internal linkage, and what are the properties they have in common?

Comment: @keelar Static storage duration means there's only one copy of that variable and its lifetime ends when the program terminates. Thread local means there's one copy per thread and its lifetime ends when the thread terminates. This is totally independent of linkage, which simply determines whether a variable is visible in other translation units.

Comment: So how about the global non-static variable?  Does that mean there's one copy per thread and its lifetime also ends when the thread terminates?

Comment: @keelar As I said, global variables automatically have static storage duration even when they are not declared `static`. If it's not explicitly `thread_local` then there will be only one copy per program and its lifetime ends when the program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled

```
int regular_global_int;
__thread int static_thread_local_int;
int main()
{
 regular_global_int = 1;
 static_thread_local_int = 1;
}
```

at http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=340 I had to take off the static to keep the optimizer from getting rid of the static variable. I got

```
main:                                   # @main
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    movl    $1, regular_global_int(%rip)
    movl    $1, %fs:static_thread_local_int@TPOFF
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
```

for the x86_64. The thread local variable is accessed differently to provide the thread local storage.